# Number Rounding

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following code written by VBA in MS Access 2010. This code prints in the Label1.caption the number of this equation.

```
the_average = CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 2 / 3 + CDbl(TextBox2.Text) / 3
the_average = Format(the_average, "#.###")
Label1.caption= the_average
```

Some of the operations have more than three decimal places. This code rounds the numbers when printing them in the caption of the label. For example if I have  1.66666666, it shows 1.667 and I want it to show 1.666 without rounding.
How can I do that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
the_average = CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 2 / 3 + CDbl(TextBox2.Text) / 3
the_average = Format(the_average, "#.####")
Label1.caption= Left(the_average,5)
```

If your final string can vary in length, you will have to use the `InStr()` function (I believe that's it).

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `Int()`'s truncation;

```
the_average = formatnumber(int(the_average * 1000) / 1000, 3)
```

You can omit `formatnumber` if you don't want trailing zeros (.99 -> .990)